kile windows default settings
I have accidentally lost the default settings of kile on windows
I searched on the web with nos success
I tried with Tools --> Modes Tools --> Highlighting
without success
thanks for help

Which settings have you lost? Have you tried to rename file kilerc? On linux/unix the file path would be ~/.config/kilerc (previously ~/.kde/share/config/kilerc). You can use the windows search to find the file. Renaming the file should switch back to the defaults. The settings for tags, menus, toolbars are AFAIK stored in kileui.rc. I don't know, if the file is also regenerated with default, if it is deleted. But renaming should be save, because you can rename it again, if something is even more broken.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
